# Zero-one linear programming with substitutable constraints

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, integer-programming

Suppose $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n$ each take values zero or one and we want to solve the following linear programming problem:

$$ 
\min_{x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_n} f(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)
$$
subject to a bunch of constraints. Suppose $f$ is linear.

Can I have one of those constraints be $x_1+x_2 \ne 1$ (or alternatively $x_1+x_2=0$ OR $x_1+x_2=2$)?

It's still a well-defined problem with a constraint like that, but can we use standard algorithms to solve it? In some sense, it seems conceptually pretty easy. My hope is that this is a pretty standard problem and one that can be easily worked with in Gurobi or CPLEX, but I've never had to work with a constraint like this before.

Comment: Solve the two problems: with $x_1+x_2=0$ and with  $x_1+x_2=2$. Then choose the better solution.

Comment: @user64494 That's true. In principle I could do that. In practice, though, if I have a lot of constraints like that, the number of problems to solve goes up exponentially.

Comment: "The feasible set would no longer be convex" but it never was. The feasible set was already ${0,1}^n$ to begin with.

Comment: @MichaelGrant. You're right. That's more misleading than helpful. I had in my mind that if the $x$'s were real then $x_1+x_2\ne1$ would make the feasible set convex, but that's not really applicable here.

Comment: True but most logical constraints can be represented using linear equations and inequalities. I am not sure of a binary constraint that cannot be.

Comment: Thanks -- that's useful to keep in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constraint is equivalent to saying $x_1=x_2$ so you can recast it into the problem:

$$\min_{x_2,\ldots,x_n} g(x_2,\ldots,x_n)$$

where

$$g(x_2,\ldots,x_n)=f(x_2,x_2,\ldots,x_n).$$

Comment: That's a useful way of thinking about it. And obvious -- not sure how it didn't occur to me! I would have a slight preference for keeping the constraint explicit in the problem (as in some cases it might be worth relaxing it), but this is a pretty good solution, which I'll accept unless a better one comes along shortly. Thanks!